# MySQL query to find the last insert code

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have codes for example:

```
PC_MB_TC_0001
PC_GH_TY_0002
PS_AB_VH_0003
IC_WC_XX_0001
IH_ML_FR_0002
```

These codes are system generated.I used the logic:First found the count of code that starts with 'P'. Then add 1 to that count.
This logic is working perfectly,but will fail when a code is deleted from database.
So is there any MySQL query to do this,or could anyone help me with some other logic.

I am using cakePhP.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: I don't follow your question.  Any chance you could explain it in more detail / better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT 1+MAX(CONVERT(RIGHT(your_column_name, 4), SIGNED)) as newindex
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column_name LIKE 'P%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use MyISAM, you can create a multi-column auto-increment that will do the work for you. You need to store the string and the auto-incrementing numbers in separate columns for this solution to work.

> For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this won't solve OP problem: he wants to increment index using only first letter of the string...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try looking at

```
echo $this->ModelName->getInsertID();
```

or

```
echo $this->ModelName->getLastInsertID();
```

Those will get you the last inserted ID of the MySQL record. Then you could look up what the code value is of that id.